# How to remove extra character or symbol from Scrapy start URL?

Tags: python, scrapy

I got a Scrapy spider and when I run the code I am getting this error

> Ignoring response <302 https://www.macys.com/>: HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed

Here is my Spider

```
import scrapy
import urllib.parse
import random

class MacysspiderSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'macysSpider'
    allowed_domains = ['macys.com']
    start_urls = ['https://macys.com']

    def parse(self, response):
        pass
```

I inspected the URL, and when I run the code it is including ">" at the end of the URL

> https://www.macys.com/>

how can I remove this UTF-8 from the start URL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure where you found the '>' as part of the url, but I don't think it has anything to do with the problem.
You need to set some headers to scrape this website:

```
headers = {
    'authority': 'www.macys.com',
    'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.100 Safari/537.36',
    'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3',
    'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'accept-language': 'en-GB,en;q=0.9,nl-BE;q=0.8,nl;q=0.7,ro-RO;q=0.6,ro;q=0.5,en-US;q=0.4',
}
```

To apply these changes into your first request you can overwrite the start_requests method as follows:

```
def start_requests(self):
    for url in self.start_urls:
        yield Request(url, headers=self.headers)
```